# Javascript Image roll over with onclick toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have code to roll over an image link as below:

```
<a id="show" href="#"><img src="images/show-me.png" border=0 onmouseover="this.src='images/show-me_over.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/show-me.png'"></a>
```

on clicking this it shows a div

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#show").toggle(
        function(){
            jQuery('#home-hidden-extra').animate({'height': '480px'} ,1000);},
        function(){
            jQuery('#home-hidden-extra').animate({'height': '0px'} ,1000);}
    );
});
```

What i would like to do but i cant find/figure out is to use show_me.png and show_me-over.png when the div is hidden and then hide_me.png and hide_me-over.png when the div is shown.

How is the simplest way to achive this?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting static hover styles to CSS. Define

```
.linkShow {
    background-image: url("images/show_me.png");
}

.linkShow:hover {
    background-image: url("images/show_me_hover.png"); 
}

.linkHide {
    background-image: url("images/hide_me.png");
}

.linkHide:hover {
    background-image: url("images/hide_me_hover.png"); 
}
```

Then add these classes to the link with jquery.

```
$("#show").removeClass().addClass("linkShow");
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

**HTML**

```
    <a id="show" href="#">
      <img id="the-image" src="images/show-me.png" />
    </a>
```

**JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setupHover(); /* Defined below */
    $('#show').toggle(function(){
        $('#home-hidden-extra').animate({'height': '480px'} ,1000);
        setupHover();
    },function(){
        $('#home-hidden-extra').animate({'height': '0px'} ,1000);
        setupHover();
    });
  });

  function setupHover(){
      /* Unbind existing hover handlers */
      $('#show').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');

      /* Use the correct image filenames depending on the situation */

      if($('#home-hidden-extra').height() > 0){
        images = ['show-me.png','show-me_over.png'];
      }
      else {
        images = ['hide_me.png','hide_me-over.png'];
      }
      $('#show').hover(function(){
          $('#the-image').attr('src','images/' + images[1]);
        },function(){
          $('#the-image').attr('src','images/' + images[0]);
        });
  }
```